# How to check two variables in if statement python?

Tags: python, if-statement

I want to check two variables or more in if state ,for example:

```
a=20
b=4
if a and b in range(1,7):
    print("yes")
```

but don't working...

Comment: ```if a in range(1,7) and b in range(1,7):```

Comment: If you want to save chain of `and` you can use `set` like `if len(set([a,b]).intersection(range(1,7)))`

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if a and b in range(1,7):
```

using

```
if a in range(1,7) and b in range(1,7):
```